# Remove White Space and "pt" in a Excel Document

Tags: excel, excel-2010

My excel table is currently like this:

```
Start        End           Speed
-------------------------------------
504 pt       1263,357  pt  21,03  pt 
538,391  pt  1223,015  pt  1,987 pt
579,486 pt   619,829  pt   235,003 pt
```

I wish to change the format to this:

```
Start    End        Speed
-------------------------------------
504      1263,357   21,03  pt 
538,391  1223,015   1,987 pt
579,486  619,829    235,003 pt
```

How do I remove the " pt" included 1 white space in every cell?

I'm using Excel 2010.

Comment: check out this: http://superuser.com/questions/554729/in-excel-2010-how-can-i-convert-cells-containing-1-day-2-days-etc-to-just/554735#comment674864_554735

Comment: Once only or via a formula?

Comment: Did want the return as a number or text?

Answer (score 3):

Use this (if you don't mind formula solution): `=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(C1,"pt",""))` - this will handle any number of spaces (your input has 2 spaces for certain case).

Comment: Nice one! I'll remember this replace with space and then trim.

Answer (score 1):

Please use the following steps:

1. If you press `<ctrl> + F` this will bring up the find window.
2. Then in the find enter " pt" and leave the replace blank.
3. Then press replace all.

**Note:**

If you want to do this on a select area simply select these first and repeat.